# how define multiple @fulltext search in a GRT subgraph?

Tags: solidity, the-graph, subgraph

I have a graphql.schema file in my subgraph(GRT)

I try to write a search for 3 entity
but the graph accepts one @fulltext type like this:

```
type _Schema_
  @fulltext(
    name: "ABXsearch"
    language: en
    algorithm: rank
    include: [{entity: "token", fields: [{ name: "id" }, { name: "metadata" }, { name: "name" }] }]
  )
```

but I want to use @fulltext for 3 entity

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
    type _Schema_
  @fulltext(
    name: "search1"
    language: en
    algorithm: rank
    include: [{ entity: "yourEntity", fields: [{ name: "name" }] }]
  )
  @fulltext(
    name: "Search2"
    language: en
    algorithm: rank
    include: [{ entity: "yourEntity2", fields: [{ name: "name" }] }]
  )
```

This is the solution